# how to plot one column as x axis and the other column as y axis in D3/javascripts

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'd like to know how to scatter plot one column(A) values to x axis and the other column(B) to y axis.  each row could have redundant values in Column A but different values in column B.   I'd like to plot unique values only in x axis.
    e.g.

```
A          B 
groupA     10
groupB     20
groupA     30
groupC     5
groupB     11
```

in x axis, plot group A, B, C without redundancy.  in y axis, plot each values belong to each group.
but instead of setting x axis values manually by pre defining A {groupA,groupB,groupC}, like to read observations automatically from column A and saves into array and plot it.
can anyone help me to start with this?

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is setting two scales, one ordinal scale for the x axis, like [`scalePoint`](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scalePoint),  and one linear scale for the y axis.

This is the x scale:

```
var xScale = d3.scalePoint()
    .domain(data.map(function(d){return d.A}))
    .range([50, width-50])
    .padding(0.5);
```

And this the y scale:

```
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){return d.B})*1.1])
    .range([height - 50, 10]);
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var data = [{A: "groupA", B: 10},
            {A: "groupB", B: 20},
            {A: "groupA", B: 30},
            {A: "groupC", B: 5},
            {A: "groupB", B: 11}]

var width = 400, height = 200;

var svg = d3.selectAll("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)
  .domain(data.map(function(d){return d.A}));

var xScale = d3.scalePoint()
  .domain(data.map(function(d){return d.A}))
  .range([50, width-50])
 .padding(0.5);
          
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){return d.B})*1.1])
  .range([height - 50, 10]);

var circles = svg.selectAll(".circles")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 8)
  .attr("cx", function(d){ return xScale(d.A)})
  .attr("cy", function(d){ return yScale(d.B)})
  .attr("fill", function(d){ return color(d.A)});
 
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,150)")
      .attr("class", "xAxis")
      .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(50,0)")
      .attr("class", "yAxis")
      .call(yAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

PS: since one scale here is ordinal (qualitative), this is not technically a scatterplot.

Comment: thanks Gerardo, this is really helpful!  btw, if there's additional rows in the datasets which is redundant to any of the rows, e.g. {A: "groupA", B: 10} is added to the dataset. but if I plot this dataset, it won't be plotted as it's already there.is there any way that I can also plot this redundant row? maybe adding little skew and transparency of circle?

Comment: @Joohun In that case, you're gonna have two circles in the same position. Just a tip: if the answer was useful, consider accepting it. Not only this helps future readers (the main purpose of SO) but makes people more inclined to helping you next time you ask a question.